# Sendgrid x-smtpapi errors with 'missing destination email'

Tags: php, email, curl, sendgrid

I've set up the following:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$file = date('YmdHis');
$fp = fopen('/var/www/mydir/files/'.$file.'.csv', 'w');

$url = 'http://sendgrid.com/';
$user = 'myuser';
$pass = 'mypass';
$to_emails = array(
  'to' => array(
    '1@example.com','2@example.com','3@example.com'
  ),
  'category' => 'Test'
);

$fileName = $file;
$filePath = dirname(__FILE__);

$params = array(
    'api_user'  => $user,
    'api_key'   => $pass,
    'x-smtpapi' => json_encode($to_emails),
    //'to' => 'example@example.com',
    'subject'   => 'Test email',
    'html'      => '<p>Testing sendgrid mail</p>',
    'text'      => 'sent',
    'from'      => 'me@example.com',
    'files['.$file.'.csv]' => '@'.$filePath.'/files/'.$fileName.'.csv'
  );

print_r($params);

$request =  $url.'api/mail.send.json';

// Generate curl request
$session = curl_init($request);

// Tell curl to use HTTP POST
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);

// Tell curl that this is the body of the POST
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);

// Tell curl not to return headers, but do return the response
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// obtain response
$response = curl_exec($session);
curl_close($session);

print_r($response);

//unlink('./files/'.$file.'.csv');

mysql_close($connect);
```

The issue is that it doesn't send to my recipients in the `$to_emails` array and outputs "missing destination email'. It does output the array of the emails I pass in but it is still looking for the "to" value in the array - I'm wondering why and how I can resolve? I've followed the Sendgrid documentation closely as far as I can see - https://sendgrid.com/docs/Code_Examples/php.html.

If I uncomment the 'to' line it sends the email to example@example.com just fine.

Answer (score 6):

The `to` parameter is currently always required *even if using the `SMTPAPI to`*. We recommend setting it to the `from` address. If the `SMTPAPI to` is present, the API will ignore the regular `to` parameter.

The example that you link to shows both `to` and `x-smtpapi` parameters present and states

> ...the email will go out to both example1@sendgrid.com and example2@sendgrid.com. The normal to address, example3@sendgrid.com, will not receive an email.

Comment: thanks for your answer. That is what I have read on the link I provided and also tried as per my question. The issue is when I set the 'to' and 'x-smtpapi' it only sends it to the 'to' email address, not to the array of emails I'd like to send it to. Documentation says 'to' is ignored but in actual fact 'x-smtpapi' is.

Comment: Could you update your question with the rest of your code please?